# URLConnection generates wrong IP checksum

Tags: java, http, urlconnection

I'm using the following code for uploading an multiform/data form with a file upload:

```
    URL url = new URL(DEST_URL);
    String boundary = "-----------------------------" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    OutputStream output = con.getOutputStream();
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_PATH));
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));

    writer.println(boundary);
    writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"input1\"");
    writer.println();
    writer.println("1234");

    writer.flush();

    writer.println(boundary);
    writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"input1\"");
    writer.println();
    writer.println("asdf");

    writer.flush();

    writer.println(boundary);
    writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file1\"; filename=\"clicknpoint.png\"");
    writer.println("Content-Type: image/png");
    writer.println();

    writer.flush();

    int length = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    for(length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    writer.flush();
    input.close();

    writer.println();
    writer.println(boundary + "--");

    writer.flush();

    input = con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

    String cur = null;
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    while((cur = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        buf.append(cur);
    }
```

The server doesn't recognizes the params in the request. I checked with wireshark, they are there but the IP header checksum is 0x0000. I think that's problem.

Any idea where this is coming from?

Comment: The checksum in Wireshark will not be correct if your system uses TCP checksum offload, which uses dedicated hardware on the NIC to calculate the checksum. This is not your issue.

Comment: So you think that's no problem. Any idea why the Firefox request, with correct checksum, is working and my code with incorrect checksum isn't?

Comment: No, I don't do much Java, but maybe someone else does. I am certain it is not the checksum, however.

Comment: @Dark Falcon - Please post this as an answer. You're absolutly correct. That's not the problem and is the fault of the NIC hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see that might be incorrect is your use of println to generate HTTP content.  Depending on your platform, the println's may be outputting a single LF character or may be outputting a CR LF pair.

HTTP definitely requires CRLF after every header. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4. Right now your code is at risk of violating the HTTP protocol. It might work on some platforms but not on others.  Also some servers might tolerate the violation of the protocol, but others might not. The least invasive change might be changing every println to print and explicitly adding the CRLF.

```
writer.print("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"input1\"\r\n");
```

This may have nothing to do with your problem, but until you tighten up your conformance with HTTP your code will be at risk of failing.

Comment: +1 - Even when it's not the problem, on a *nix it doesn't work with println and on Mac OS it does. Because ln is different on the systems.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already realized, you are looking at two independent issues: Wireshark is showing an invalid checksum, and your server is not correctly receiving data.

**Issue 1: Wireshark is showing an invalid checksum**

I realize you've already figured out that this is because of TCP checksum offloading. For posterity, I'll repeat what you already know.

On modern computers, the OS does not calculate a checksum for each TCP packet it sends out. Instead, the checksum is calculated in hardware on the Network adapter. Since Wireshark is intercepting packets before they reach the network adapter, it sees the wrong checksum. To confirm that offloading is in fact the reason you are seeing invalid checksums in Wireshark, you can temporarily turn it off. For Mac OS X, use these commands in Terminal:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.link.ether.inet.apple_hwcksum_tx=0
sudo sysctl -w net.link.ether.inet.apple_hwcksum_rx=0
```

To re-enable after testing, just replace those 0s with 1s. To disable offloading on other operating systems, [here](https://www.eff.org/wp/detecting-packet-injection) in the section *Step 3. If possible, disable TCP and UDP checksum offloading and TCP segmentation offloading*.

**Issue 2: Server is not correctly receiving data**

URLConnection objects are *not* reusable. And calling flush() or write() on the output stream of a URLConnection immediately sends your request. After that, you must create a new URLConnection. Make sure that all your data has been added to the output stream before calling either of these methods. A really excellent discussion of the consequences of manipulating the I/O streams of URLConnections can be found here: 
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2001/jw-0323-traps.html?page=4

Comment: I totally forgot my question here. In the mean time I got it fixed. The problem was the newline and the boundaries. It wasn't the checksum or the flush.